# Android Auto app never calls onGetRoot

Tags: android, android-auto

I'm developing an audio streaming application for Android and integrating Android Auto. I've been following these two tutorials.

[Android Developer Training](https://developer.android.com/training/auto/start/index.html)

[PTR Android Blog](http://ptrprograms.blogspot.com/2015/02/using-android-auto-media-browser.html)

Using the Desktop Head Unit, I'm able to select my media app from the media app list, but from there a `ProgressBar` stays instead of giving way to the "To play something, open the menu at the top left." message seen in the [Universal Music Player](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-UniversalMusicPlayer).

On inspection, it seems that the `MediaBrowserServiceCompat`'s `onGetRoot()`is never invoked and thus never populating my `MediaItemCompat` into the Auto app's list.

My manifest contains the following.

```
<manifest package="com.app.audio"
      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MEDIA_CONTENT_CONTROL"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>

<application
    android:name="com.app.audio.AudioApp"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">


    <activity
        android:name="com.app.audio.presentation.home.HomeActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:launchMode="singleTop">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name="com.app.audio.presentation.weather.WeatherActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="userPortrait"/>

    <activity android:name="com.app.audio.presentation.settings.SettingsActivity"/>

    <activity android:name="com.app.audio.presentation.alarm.AlarmActivity"/>

    <activity android:name="com.app.audio.presentation.sleep.SleepActivity"/>

    <receiver android:name="com.app.audio.audio.AudioIntentReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MEDIA_BUTTON"/>
            <action android:name="android.media.AUDIO_BECOMING_NOISY"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <receiver android:name="com.app.audio.presentation.alarm.AlarmReceiver"></receiver>

    <receiver android:name="com.app.audio.presentation.sleep.SleepReceiver"></receiver>

    <service
        android:name="com.app.audio.data.service.media.MediaService"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.media.browse.MediaBrowserService"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </service>

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.car.application"
        android:resource="@xml/automotive_app_desc"/>

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.car.notification.SmallIcon"
        android:resource="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>
</application>
```

My `automotive_app_desc.xml` is very simple, only declaring Media.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<automotiveApp>
    <uses name="media"/>
</automotiveApp>
```

My `MediaService` extends `MediaBrowserServiceCompat`. In the `onCreate()` I create and set my `MediaSessionCompat`.

```
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    //...
    mediaSession = new MediaSessionCompat(
            this,
            SESSION_TAG,
            mediaIntentReceiver,
            null
    );

    mediaSession.setFlags(
            MediaSessionCompat.FLAG_HANDLES_MEDIA_BUTTONS |
                    MediaSessionCompat.FLAG_HANDLES_TRANSPORT_CONTROLS);

    mediaSession.setCallback(new MediaSessionCompat.Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onPlay() {
            super.onPlay();
            play(selectedStream);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPause() {
            super.onPause();
            pause();
        }

        @Override
        public void onStop() {
            super.onStop();
            stop();
        }

        @Override
        public void onSkipToNext() {
            super.onSkipToNext();
            playNextStation();
        }

        @Override
        public void onSkipToPrevious() {
            super.onSkipToPrevious();
            playPreviousStation();
        }
    });

    mediaSession.setActive(true);
    setSessionToken(mediaSession.getSessionToken());
    updatePlaybackState(ACTION_STOP);
}
```

Finally, the two overridden methods from `MediaBrowserServiceCompat`, of which neither is ever called.

```
@Nullable
@Override
public BrowserRoot onGetRoot(@NonNull String clientPackageName, int clientUid, @Nullable Bundle rootHints) {
    return new BrowserRoot(ROOT_ID, null);
}

@Override
public void onLoadChildren(@NonNull String parentId, @NonNull Result<List<MediaBrowserCompat.MediaItem>> result) {
    List<MediaBrowserCompat.MediaItem> items = getMediaItemsById(parentId);
    if (items != null) {
        result.sendResult(items);
    }
}
```

As far as I can tell, that's everything required to get an Android Auto started, yet when I open the app on my desktop head unit, there is only a `ProgressBar` greeting me, and when I open the off-screen nav drawer, there's another one. I haven't heard of that state in any material I've read. Is there something I missed?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Ultimately, the issue didn't have anything to do with what I described. The aforementioned `MediaService` also does other tasks that require a custom `Binder`. This custom `Binder` didn't call the `onGetRoot()` needed for the Head Unit. As a solution, I check the `Intent` action and return `super.onBind()` when it's from the `MediaBrowserServiceCompat`.

```
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    if (SERVICE_INTERFACE.equals(intent.getAction())) {
        return super.onBind(intent);
    }
    return new MediaBinder();
}
```

The `SERVICE_INTERFACE` is a constant in `MediaBrowserServiceCompat`.

Comment: Thanks so much for posting this solution. I've been debugging this for hours.

Comment: Yes, thank you! Just to mention it since my initial searches were fruitless, returning my own custom Binder instead of MediaBrowserServiceCompat's also resulted in errors getting logged: "[my.package.name]: oneway function results will be dropped but finished with status UNKNOWN_TRANSACTION and parcel size 0". These went away (and Android Auto started working) after I made the change described here.

Answer (score 0):

I'm developing an Android auto but I have some problems in this part of my code, in `Onbind` method of the service:

```
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
    Log.i("TAG", "OnBind");
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if (SERVICE_INTERFACE.equals(arg0.getAction())) {
        Log.i("TAG", "SERVICE_INTERFACE");
        registerReceiver(receiver, filter);
        return super.onBind(arg0);
    } else { 
        Log.i("Musica Service", "musicBind");
        return musicBind;}
}
```

I have other activities bound with my service through a `musicBind IBinder`, but on the other hand I have set all things to connect my app in Android auto interface but after close my app after disconnect the device from the android auto I can't stop my `mediabrowserservice` compat. I think it's due to this `SERVICE_INTERFACE` keeps binded the service. How can I stop or destroy this from the same `servicemediabrowserservicecompat`?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This is not an answer to the question, it's a comment/new question. Once you have 

sufficient reputation (50) you will be able to comment on any post. In the meantime you can gain reputation 

[**asking your own questions**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) or [**providing answers on 

subjects**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).